# Excel: Read special characters

Tags: excel, character, encode

How can i read special characters in excel. For example `ö` is changed into `Ã¶` and a hyphen (-) is changed in to `â€`

Is there any way to make it read all my characters like it should?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you import a text file that contains those characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "special characters" you mean non-ASCII standard characters. You probably need to convert your file's encoding to Unicode (UTF-8). The way I do it is to open it up in notepad++ and hit convert to UTF-8. Save the file and it should open up in excel

Comment: I opened the excel file in notepad++, went to menu coding -> chose UTF-8, saved it.

Now I opened it in excel but I got an error that it couldn't open it because the file format or file extention (extention didn't change) is not valid. Do I have to do something before i save it?

Comment: Hmm, well there goes the quick fix. Do you know what encoding was used to save the file? If not what is the source for the file.

Comment: I had 2 files, a CSV and a XLSX. I tried it first to change the encoding with the XLSX file and it failed, but the CSV file does it perfectly. Thanks, it works like a charm now.